# Looking for an enhanced WebClient/HttpWebRequest with Fiddler-like info - is there one?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Before I get too deep in creating this, is there a library out there for .NET that provides Fiddler-like statistics in a `HttpWebRequest` / `WebClient` request?

Some things I'm looking for:

1. Time to First Byte
2. Caching Headers
3. Response Codes
4. Transfer Rate (bytes/sec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/)? It is the fiddler library which you can include with your own .NET application. From the web page:

> FiddlerCore allows you to integrate HTTP/HTTPS traffic viewing and
>   modification capabilities into your .NET application, without any of
>   the Fiddler UI.

Eric Lawrence also did a recent .NET Rocks episode with some more background information in case you are interested.